# Pixate Status Bar Text Color

Tags: ios, ios7, pixate

The colour of the text in my status bar appears black rather white.

The CSS i'm using to style the navigation bar is:

```
navigation-bar {
    background-color: black;
    shadow: none;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the text to be white so the user can actually see it?

Thanks

Comment: What version of iOS are you running this on?

Comment: Are you certain the status bar's is even visible? Can you see the battery?

Comment: Hi, Yep I can see the battery icon, carrier and time but its in black.

Comment: Maybe this is overkill, but can you add a screen shot with the status bar and the navigation bar? Also, if you're using a navigation controller make sure the `-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` is applied to the proper view controller.

Answer (score 0):

To edit the status bar style for your app, rather than the navigation bar, you can always set the `statusBarStyle` property on `UIApplication` like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Or on a per-view controller basis add this to your view controller's implementation:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a Pixate style rule that would allow you to change the status bar color or style.

Comment: Thanks however thats changing the colour of the text in the navigation bar itself. Not the status bar

Comment: Got it - Corrected the answer to something that might work better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do since you say "status" bar in your question (which is the bar at the top with the carrier, time, and battery icon), but it looks like you mean navigation bar. :)

If that's the case, you can style its title like this:

```
navigation-bar title {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20;
  /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: No, they meant status bar.

Comment: Thats right i.e. where the carrier, time and battery icon is